# How do I create a tuple with an attribute using Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples

I have a class WeightedArc defined as follows:

```
class Arc(tuple):

  @property
  def tail(self):
    return self[0]

  @property
  def head(self):
    return self[1]

  @property
  def inverted(self):
    return Arc((self.head, self.tail))

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.head == other.head and self.tail == other.tail

class WeightedArc(Arc):
  def __new__(cls, arc, weight):
    self.weight = weight
    return super(Arc, cls).__new__(arc)
```

This code clearly doesn't work, because `self` isn't defined for `WeightArc.__new__`.  How do I assign the attribute weight to the WeightArc class?

Comment: Why are you using __new__ instead of __init__?

Comment: Er, I thought __init__ didn't work tuples. I think my understanding of __new__ is way off.

Comment: You're right.  Init does not work for tuples.  They are fully populated by __new__.

Comment: It really depends on whether you want 'weight' to go in an instance dictionary (if so, the init will work on the subclass).  If you want weight as a field in the tuple, you can extend the definition as shown in the namedtuple example below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fixed-up version of your original code is:

```
class WeightedArc(Arc):
    def __new__(cls, arc, weight):
        self = tuple.__new__(cls, arc)
        self.weight = weight
        return self
```

Another approach to look at the *verbose* option for *collections.namedtuple* to see an example of how to subclass *tuple*:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
>>> _property = property
>>> from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
>>> Arc = namedtuple('Arc', ['head', 'tail'], verbose=True)
class Arc(tuple):
    'Arc(head, tail)' 

    __slots__ = () 

    _fields = ('head', 'tail') 

    def __new__(_cls, head, tail):
        'Create new instance of Arc(head, tail)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (head, tail)) 

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new Arc object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != 2:
            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
        return result 

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        return 'Arc(head=%r, tail=%r)' % self 

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self)) 

    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new Arc object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('head', 'tail'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % kwds.keys())
        return result 

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self) 

    head = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')
    tail = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
```

You can cut, paste, and modify this code, or just subclass from it as shown in the [namedtuple docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

To extend this class, build off of the fields in Arc:

```
WeightedArc = namedtuple('WeightedArc', Arc._fields + ('weight',))
```

Comment: I just edited to show how to modify your original code as well as showing the namedtuple() approach.  For the latter, I also added the same imports used by the real collections module.

Answer (score 2):

> Another approach to look at the verbose option for collections.namedtuple to see an example of how to subclass tuple

Better yet, why not use namedtuple ourselves? :)

```
class Arc(object):
    def inverted(self):
        d = self._asdict()
        d['head'], d['tail'] = d['tail'], d['head']
        return self.__class__(**d)

class SimpleArc(Arc, namedtuple("SimpleArc", "head tail")): pass

class WeightedArc(Arc, namedtuple("WeightedArc", "head tail weight")): pass
```